# Normalizer with respect to a compact subgroup

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a semisimple Lie group with $K$ to be the compact subgroup in the Iwasawa decomposition $G=KAN.$ Then, if $\mathfrak a$ is the Lie algebra of $A$ what is $N_K(\mathfrak a)$ which is referred as normalizer in Knapp's book? I can understand the meaning of $N_{\mathfrak g}(\mathfrak a)$ which is the normalizer of $\mathfrak a$ in $\mathfrak g,$ i.e. the smallest subalegbra in which $\mathfrak a$ becomes an ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knapp does not define it explicitly but this notation usually means
$$N_K(\mathfrak{a})=\{ k\in K: Ad(k)(\mathfrak{a})=\mathfrak{a}\},$$
which is consistent with how he uses it (see e.g. Prop. 6.52). This is how Duistermaat (Section 2.8) defines it.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. You can accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Can you also tell me what Knapp means by $Z_K(\mathfrak a)$? This comes after Corollary 6.55. May be all $k\in K$ such that $Ad(k)\mathfrak a=0$?!!

Comment: It should be $\{k\in K: Ad(k)(H) = H\ \forall H\in\mathfrak{a}\}$, i.e. elements in $K$ so that $\mathfrak{a}$ is not just $Ad(k)$-invariant but so that $Ad(k)$ acts as the identity on $\mathfrak{a}$.